# Reducing the number of queries, possibly through the table schema?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm retrieving data from an api that looks like:

```
[{"type": "a", "value": 1, "identifier": 1},
{"type": "b", "value": 9, "identifier": 1},
{...},{...},
{"type": "a", "value": 2, "identifier": n}]
```

The identifier can be any value between 1-500, and it's not guaranteed  that all records will have the same identifiers. If an identifier is present, it will have all of the same types and a particular range of values. What I was initially using to update the records looked like this:

```
api_data.each do |x|
  temp = Object.find_or_create_by_type_and_identifier_and_id(x["type]", x["identifier"], user_id)
  temp.update_attributes(x)
end
```

This is incredibly slow, and running about 2200 queries each time this data is loaded. Once to see if the data exists, then once to update, for 1100 entries. The table scheme currently being used looks like:

```
create table ( type, identifier, id, value)
```

This is `obviously inefficient`, I just didn't realize how much so. What should I attempt to reduce the number of queries, so that the application isn't going to crawl when it needs to update or pull a new users data?

A method that has been suggested is to mass insert, and delete the previous entries when in need of updating, which would reduce this to 2, but I'm not sure if that's the best method.

Comment: Do a mass insert into a staging table and update the main table from that.

Comment: or use threads to speedup

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do bulk updating, you might be able to get away with [ActiveRecord::Relation#update_all](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all), depending on the nature of the updates.

The [activerecord-import gem](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/wiki/Examples) does efficient bulk inserts.  I'm not sure if it has an update mechanism, but it's great for inserting quickly (a single SQL statement for thousands of rows).  It'd only take one fast query for the ~2200 records, some update logic, and a single statement to insert missing records.

A moderately more extreme but possibly much faster solution might be to load every record in the DB, reconcile the new state, delete all the rows you want to delete or change (fast bulk operation), and bulk insert new/modified ones with activerecord-import.  That would be at most three database operations and would run very quickly for ~2200 records, but not quickly enough that you'd want to do it on every change.

Finally, you could resort to SQL.  It looks like your change is basic enough that you could simply do `YourModel.connection.execute "UPDATE some_things SET foo = 'whatever'"`.  I suspect there's a Railsy way to do whatever you want, though.  Check out the [ActiveRecord](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) documentation.  There are many bulk operations like `delete_all`, `update_all`, etc.

Comment: update all is essentially doing WHERE x=y, which won't work in this case as the data is heterogeneous. I'm looking more into the staging idea mentioned in the comments above, but as of right now I `am` using connection.execute to solve this problem. I'm hoping for a more `rails`-esc answer, but this is what I'm going with so far.